# How to getFilter() in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, arraylist, baseadapter

I develop app with a EditText searching in a listView . my Adapter is cusom by BaseAdapter.
I found on the google some tutorials but it seems is not working . i have many person names in a ArrayList and when i'm tring to type the name in EditText i'ts show me the all list.

here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Person> contactList;
    CustomContact adapterContact;

    //Temp
    ArrayList<String> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> groupListName = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Person> tempList;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);

        txTempName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTempName);



        edNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edPhoneOrName);
        edMass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edMass);

        timepicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerMain);
        timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePickerMain);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContact);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);





        edNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    refreshContact();
                } else {
                    MainActivity.this.adapterContact.getFilter().filter(s);

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });

}

    public void refreshContact(){
    DbHandContact hand = new DbHandContact(this);
    hand.open();
    contactList  = hand.getAll();
    hand.close();
    Collections.sort(contactList,contactSort); 
    adapterContact = new CustomContact(this, contactList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapterContact);

    tempList = (ArrayList<Person>) contactList.clone();

}

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if(true){


                String currentCellPhone = tempList.get(position).getCellPhone();
                String name = tempList.get(position).getName();

                groupList.add(currentCellPhone);
                groupListName.add(name);

                Toast.makeText(this, currentCellPhone+" "+name, 2000).show();

                for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                    txTempName.setText(groupList.get(i));
                }

            }
        }



CustomAdapter
My Adapter class:

    public class CustomContact extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        Activity context;
        ArrayList<Person> list;


        protected ArrayList<String> temporarylist;

        public CustomContact(Activity context, ArrayList<Person> list) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row;
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, parent,false);

            ImageView imgPerson,ImgDial;
            TextView txName,txLastName,txCellnum,HomeNum;

            txName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
            txLastName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_lastName);
            txCellnum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_cellNum);


            imgPerson = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_picture);


            txName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            txLastName.setText(list.get(position).getLastName());
            txCellnum.setText(list.get(position).getCellPhone());


            return row;
        }

         @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
                Filter filter = new Filter() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                            FilterResults results) {
                        list = (ArrayList<Person>) results.values;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                        ArrayList<Person> FilteredList = new ArrayList<Person>();
                        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                            // No filter implemented we return all the list
                            results.values = list;
                            results.count = list.size();

                        } else {

                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                String data = list.get(i).getName();


                                if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {

                                    FilteredList.add(list.get(i));
                                }


                            }
                            results.values = FilteredList;
                            results.count = FilteredList.size();

                        }

                        return results;
                    }
                };

                return filter;
            }

    }
```

It's works fine but after i filter i get the wrong position of the list item

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have set the same data in all the items in your array list

```
list = new ArrayList<Person>();
list.add(new Person(0, "A", "af", "dasds", "ASdfas", ""));
list.add(new Person(0, "B", "af", "dasds", "ASdfas", ""));
list.add(new Person(0, "C", "af", "dasds", "ASdfas", ""));
list.add(new Person(0, "D", "af", "dasds", "ASdfas", ""));
list.add(new Person(0, "E", "af", "dasds", "ASdfas", ""));
```

Can you try changing the data?

Comment: I know that but I need to find the getName(). and its A B C D E.

Comment: Ok Looks like you are editing not editing the main list object when you publish the result. Android will Take your data from the adapter itself. So after you filter your data make sure that the temporarylist object data gets reflected back to main list.

Comment: Make a copy of the array that you are using into another variable. Then filter the data on the main list. In your addTextChangedListener if the string is empty then you need to re-initialize the list using the temp list. You might also have to write some additional getter methods in your adapter class, to update your Activity list.

Comment: Ok . sound very complex. you can be more specific or give me a example please... ?

Comment: sure.. I'm using the editText for type the name I want . now when I type "g" the adapter give me all the names with the "g" letter . but when I try to research "g" again the adapter not given me it's seems like the tempList remove the name with"g" letter. but when I call onCreate again it's work fine until I search the next letter... I hope you understand my english not so good

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.testproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText ed;
ArrayList<Person> mlist;
ListView lv;
CustomContact adapter;
ArrayList<Person> tempList;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mlist = new ArrayList<Person>();
    mlist.add(new Person(0, "A"));
    mlist.add(new Person(0, "B"));
    mlist.add(new Person(0, "C"));
    mlist.add(new Person(0, "D"));
    mlist.add(new Person(0, "E"));

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new CustomContact(this, mlist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    tempList = (ArrayList<Person>) mlist.clone();

    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mlist = (ArrayList<Person>) tempList.clone();
            } else {
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            setVisibiltyList();

        }
    });

}

public void setVisibiltyList() {
    if (ed.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

class CustomContact extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Activity context;

    public CustomContact(Activity context, ArrayList<Person> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        mlist = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(mlist.get(position).name);

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                mlist = (ArrayList<Person>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<Person> FilteredList = new ArrayList<Person>();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    // No filter implemented we return all the list
                    results.values = mlist;
                    results.count = mlist.size();

                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < mlist.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mlist.get(i).name;

                        if (data.toLowerCase().contains(
                                constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            FilteredList.add(mlist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = FilteredList;
                    results.count = FilteredList.size();
                }

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }

}

class Person {

    public String name;

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you alot !!!! but..It works but after you run a few searches it can not find and seemed empty list. you know why?! example: if i search some one and the first char of his name starts with "k" So other people whose name starts with "K" that does not appear to me after. Even though they are there... any idea?!

Comment: i dint understand what you said. Can you please elobrate?

Comment: i am trying to sort the list by EditText using filter in adapter. Filter is processing well but the position of listview click is always constant. i.e. ListView is getting filter but after selection of item its taking the same position in the list view.

Comment: can you share a code snippet of what you are doing?

Comment: No one can slove that problem :((((